# JPA - Hibernate : Select query on the continuously growing table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have a Mysql table which holds about 10 million records currently. Records are inserted by another batch application on continues basis and keep on growing.
On the front end user can search the data on this table based on different criterion. I am using query DSL and JPA repository to create dynamic queries and getting data from the table. But the performance of the query with pagination is very slow. I have tried indexing, InnoDB related tweaks,session management by HikariCP and ehcahe solutions but still it is taking about 100 seconds to get the data.
Also entities are simple POJO with no relation with other entities.

What is the best way/technology/framework to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

In a table of this size, dynamic query is a really, REALLY bad idea, you need to really control the access to the table and avoid table scans at all cost.

Ultimately, this sounds like a data warehouse solution, whereas the data is ETL'ed into a report-like format and not raw transactional data.  Even so, you'll still need to define the access patterns you need and design your DWH to support that.

If you decide that the raw data is still the best format, another approach would be to define support metadata tables that could be queried to more quickly reduce the number of rows returned.

Could also look at clustering the data if you can find some way to logically break out data into chunks.  However, when you say dynamic queries, this might not be possible.

Comment: I concur with Sosna. I would also suggest Scharding the large table. That is breaking the table into N tables and host each table (schard) on the same host or preferably different hosts. You can do this manually (old school) or perhaps there is some product that helps. If you can schard the table on the query parameter then you might be able to determine during query time *which* table to perform the query. Otherwise you will need to perform the query on all tables (shards) simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a dedicated cache and the web app should query the cache instead of the DB. If the ETL batch to your main table is at a defined period, you can keep the cache hot by triggering a loading from the main table to the cache. This can any in memory cache like Ignite or Infinispan.
However, this is not a sustainable solution and eventually you would need to restrict your users into seeing data within a manageable date range only and will have to either discard or send the old data asynchronous via flat file generated reports.
Not the entire history of the huge dataset can be made available in the UI to the user.

You could also try data virtualization tools to figure out what users are more comfortable with before deciding on the partition strategy in production.